# emacs artist-mode bind right click to menu

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'd realy like to use emacs-artist mode to document my code as seen here: http://www.cinsk.org/emacs/emacs-artist.html

But I can't access the menu like in the screen cast. It seems that the menu is boud to the 3rd (middle) mouse button. But my mouse has only 2 buttons.

How can I reconfigure my emacs key binding for emacs artist-mode that it uses the 2nd (right) mouse button for the menu?

I'd like to set the binding only for artist-mode of course.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you haven't done so already, go ahead and open up `artist.el` and have a look at the key assignments for the `artist-mode-map`.  Once you understand what is assigned, you can start modifying the assignments as Stefan is suggesting in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I put in my .emacs.el

```
(eval-after-load "artist"
   '(define-key artist-mode-map [(down-mouse-3)] 'artist-mouse-choose-operation)
   )
```

Thanks for the right hints!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, the right button is the one Emacs calls `mouse-3` and the middle buttong is the one Emacs calls `mouse-2`.  You should report this problem via `M-x report-emacs-bug` because I think it's a bug.

You can fix this problem with something like:

```
(define-key artist-mode-map [down-mouse-3] 'artist-mouse-choose-operation)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to add this `(eval-after-load "artist-mode"
  '(progn
    (define-key artist-mode-map [down-mouse-2] 'artist-mouse-choose-operation)
    )
  )` to my .emacs.el but it doesn't work.

Comment: And I don't think the key binding is a bug. Left button is 'painting', right button is 'erasing' and middle button is the context menu, by default.

Comment: I know, but I think it might be considered a bug, because Emacs usually uses the right button to bring up a menu, so artist maybe should too.